# How to get a Prototype Scoped Osgi Component (which turn out to also be Vaadin component) reference programmatically

Tags: osgi, vaadin21

I am using Vaadin 21 in Apache Karaf, an Osgi container.
What i want to do :

- Create a vaadin Component, annotates it with @Component(scope=ScopeService.PROTOTYPE)
- In the View with the @Route, the Vaadin doc says that we cannot use injection dependency to get the Osgi Component reference
- To get the reference, the doc says to use :

  ````
  ServiceReference<MyComponent> reference = ctx.getServiceReference(MyService.class);
  MyComponent myComponent = ctx.getService(reference);```
  ````
- I have a problem when i refresh my screen, the instance of MyComponent stays the same
- To avoid that, i found an alternative :

  ````
      ServiceReference<MyComponent> reference = ctx.getServiceReference(MyComponent.class);
      ServiceObjects<MyComponent> res = ctx.getServiceObjects(reference);
      MyComponent myComponent = res.getService();```
  ````

Has anyone got a better way to get my Prototype vaadin and osgi component Reference ?
Here is my code (from base-starter-flow-osgi) :

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        
        BundleContext ctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyComponent.class).getBundleContext();
        ServiceReference<MyComponent> reference = ctx.getServiceReference(MyComponent.class);
        ServiceObjects<MyComponent> res = ctx.getServiceObjects(reference);
        prestas = res.getService();

        add(myComponent);
    }
}
@Component(service=MyComponent.class, scope=ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)
public class MyComponent extends Div{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8573895829405499446L;

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent);
        add(new Span("Hello World!"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) What's the benefit of using prototype scope over just creating a `new` Component instance in your case? 2) What is the problem with your alternative solution (why are you searching for a "better" way)?

Comment: @ollitietavainen thanks for your reply
1) i'd like to use full osgi potential with `@Component` that handles instances lifecycle, dependencies injection, etc. for example, if MyComponent uses some services, here, i just annotates with `Reference` and use bundle context to get MyComponent reference, initialized with its service instances.
2) it seems a litlle complicated or at least verbose to get a component instance, that's why we hesitated using, like you said, new instance. But we're in an osgi environnement so we're looking for a lighter way, more readable, to improve our code

Comment: Maybe you could update your MyComponent example to include a service injection if that's your use case (try to be specific about what you're asking). And in my humble opinion, injection is always less readable than direct instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified processes to your solution.

```
public class OSGIServiceUtil {

  private static final Map<Class<?>, ContextReference<?>> references = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public static <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    ContextReference<?> reference = references.computeIfAbsent(clazz, k -> {
      BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(clazz).getBundleContext();
      return new ContextReference<>(bundleContext, bundleContext.getServiceReference(clazz));
    });
    // The casting part you can have special handling based on your company code style
    return (T) reference.getService();
  }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
class ContextReference<T> {

  private BundleContext bundleContext;
  private ServiceReference<T> reference;

  T getService() {
    return bundleContext.getServiceObjects(reference).getService();
  }
}
```

In client

```
MyComponent myComponent = OSGIServiceUtil.get(MyComponent.class);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?